# Android Material design layout sample

Tags: android, layout, components, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I'm implementing my first app with Material design and would like to create the layout that is mentioned in the introduction page: http://www.google.co.uk/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html#

[image]

But I couldn't find what this specific layout is called and I couldn't find any samples for this. Ideally I want to have this layout with the new Navigation Drawer. Appreciate any links/samples that are related to this.

Comment: https://github.com/kanytu/android-material-drawer-template A good place to start

Comment: Pedro, I am able to create sample applications from Android Studio. My question is regarding the particular layout that is specified above. Any idea what those components are called?

Comment: Floating button + CardView + Toolbar.

Comment: Thank you Pedro. Any idea how I can get Navigation Drawer with the Toolbar?

Comment: Yes just check the template I posted. Like I said it's a good place to start.

Comment: I tried using the template but I'm getting a strange error if I try to combine Toolbar and the Navigation Drawer. Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.app.ActionBar.getThemedContext()' on a null object reference
            at com.poliveira.apps.materialtests.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateView(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:102)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start from the very beginning, the Android tutorials: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: Sipty, I have created many Android apps before. My question is regarding the Material design layout thats specified in the above question. Any idea what those components are called?

Comment: Oh, haha, my apologies! I believe this is what you're looking for: http://developer.android.com/training/material/index.html ... Unless I am misunderstanding your question still? :P